# Can Jupyter Notebooks be hosted or otherwise published on 11ty/Eleventy websites?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, eleventy

Has anyone any suggestions on how to embed or host Jupyter notebooks, or Jupyter notebooks saved as `.html`, on [11ty](https://www.11ty.dev/) websites?

I've tried downloading notebooks as `.html`, storing them in `./src/_includes/` and trying to embed them in a markdown page like this:

```html
{% include "notebook.html" %}
```

Unfortunately, it publishes as raw code:

```bash
/-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Copyright (c) Jupyter Development Team.
| Distributed under the terms of the Modified BSD License.
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------/

/*
The following CSS variables define the main, public API ...
```

I tried an iframe shortcode:

```js
eleventyConfig.addShortcode('getNotebook', (arg) => `<iframe src="${arg}">`);
```

But it seems the system doesn't care for iframes: `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).`

I tried downloading the notebook as markdown but that doesn't work that awfully well - the formatting quickly goes haywire, and interactive graphs are a disaster. If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way around this. It's a bit of a hack, but it works.

My original problem was that using `{% include "notebook.html" %}` in a markdown file caused the html to render as raw code, rather than html. However, that doesn't happen if the `include` is in the `.njk` template, rather than markdown.

So, every notebook I post now has to have its own special template, which is an `include` directive to an individual notebook. The markdown file contains only the front matter. All the action is in the template, and in a notebooks folder in the `src/_includes` folder.

It's very McGyver, but as long as it works I'm prepared to live with the loss of elegance.

Answer (score -1):

I would use global data files (i.e. jupyter.js) to fetch the data and create the collection which can then be rendered as html anywhere on the site using any template you fancy.

Comment: Do you think you could add a little more detail? Maybe explain what you mean by "jupyter.js" or point out how this would solve the problems I outlined in the original question?